# show blog when using filter category wise on same page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, blogs, categories

I have made the blog for my website using blog designer plugin for grid view UI. And use the shortcode to display the blog on page template.i want to add one search form above where all blog show and in that search form i want to filter all blog category wise. when i clicked on any category only selected category blog show on same page where all blog show to filter. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2oWy.png)

Please tell me if anyone have any idea.
i used this to search 

        " method="get">

```
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'show_option_none' => __( 'Select category' ),
        'show_count'       => 1,
        'orderby'          => 'name',
        'echo'             => 0,
                    'class'            => 'form-control',
    );
    ?>

    <?php $select  = wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>
    <?php $replace = "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>"; ?>
    <?php $select  = preg_replace( '#<select([^>]*)>#', $replace, $select ); ?>

    <?php echo $select; ?>

    <noscript>
        <input type="submit" value="View" />
    </noscript>

</form>
```

Comment: you can use ajax. did you try with ajax?

Comment: and this shortcode used to show blog <?php echo do_shortcode("[pt_view id=c8a7a54j7b]"); ?>

Comment: and i made the blog to wordpress posts and want to filter this posts according to category

Comment: check this link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35849/using-ajax-on-categories-and-wordpress-loops